# Colors too bright on laptop monitor when extended

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, brightness, extended-desktop

I have a laptop and an external monitor set as my primary, when I extend to my laptop monitor using "Windows + P" my laptop screen is a little too bright, but automatically fixes itself when I open Display Settings. Any ideas why and how to make my laptop monitor display correct brightness without me needing to go to Display Settings every time I extend my display?

I'm on Windows 10, my display GPU is Intel HD Graphics 4600, any other info I need to specify?

Comment: It's probably referred to Intel Graphics Panel settings. Try to adjust anything from there, squeeze the options little bit, and or choose the displays which will have that adjust, set it to manual or Default.

Comment: No noteworthy settings there, if I'm looking at the right place: https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/images/graphics/sb/img/picture1.jpg
All of the settings seems to be the same for both my monitors on all of the tabs and there's only one profile set.

Comment: But there's an option at the middle left side of screen where oyu select other monitors, try to go to that monitor and first deactivate then second delete that profile, and as I've said change it to manual configuration, set a value to see if works!

Answer (score 0):

I will give it some options:

First things first:

- check the cable/change the cable
- check the same monitor on another machine

Then,

1. Power options:
   Try to deactivate all sleeping values, including display put the equivalent of permanent.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuBcj.jpg)

2. Does your monitor do the same error without the second display connected?
3. Update your Intel graphics
4. Try to uninstall your Intel graphics if nothing works for the sake of knowing if it's really your Intel driver the problem.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9IxX.jpg)

5. Does your monitor has "automatic brightness"?
6. Try this method [Solved: Windows 10 brightness not working (can’t adjust screen brightness) 2020](https://windows101tricks.com/windows-10-brightness-not-working/)
7. Try this method [Dual monitors - the second monitor is very dim](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/dual-monitors-the-second-monitor-is-very-dim/d1d68465-6d81-4403-a694-bc8b73d478ff)

### Helpful

[Group Policy](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-directory-services-team/managing-power-with-group-policy-part-2-of-3/ba-p/395124) power management

To be continued...!!